# Adding local folder and NFS share under same folder

Tags: linux, nfs

I have repository server with a lot of files and data, that being used by a few nodes. Lately, I came across the issue of high load on the repository due to high volume of reads from nodes.

What I wanted to do, is to have some recent data(sliding window), that being used most frequently, locally on the nodes, luckly I have some SSD space on nodes.
Only few jobs, that are running on nodes require old data from the repository itself.
Now the question is, is there any option to combine data from NFS share and locally stored under the same folder. Application that uses data doesn't quite have an option to go to different folders.
Structure is the following:

```
> Share: /data/YYYY/YYYYMM/.....
> Local: /local/YYYY/YYYYMM/.... (But only last 3 months)
```

I want to mount it under same folder, `/mnt` for instance, that `/mnt/2015/201512` will be on local SSD and `/mnt/2015/201511` will be available from repository server

Comment: Hallo AlexiusFlavius, strictly speaking when you mount two file systems on the same mount point, only the last one mounted is visible.

Comment: Hey, you're correct, basically I need to mount few local folders inside NFS share, if I can say it that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *could* use something like overlayfs:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt

There are similar SW packages like aufs or UnionFS. aufs is, afaik, outdated.

I have no experience with these software packages and it seems like a ugly thing to do. I would try to solve the Problem with a read cache added to the NFS Server. Just make it big enough and let it run for a while, from your description you should get decent hit rates.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the advise, read cache looks good, it's sad, that I don't have enough resources to cache the amount of data I need, but it's very good point

Answer (score 2):

The nfs client in Linux has a native support for caching data on local disk - so called **CacheFS**. In most cached, you need simply configure where to store the data and tell client with a mount option to enable local caching. Check [CentOS / RHEL CacheFS: Speed Up NFS Access](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/centos-redhat-install-configure-cachefilesd-for-nfs/) for details.

Comment: Hey, already using cacheFS, found it few days before your post, 10x